# cucumber 2.0.0 not compatible with RubyMine 6.x and TeamCity formatter

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cucumber, rubymine

I am trying to set up Cucumber within my automated test suite. I am using Ruby 2.0 at the moment, but have also had this same issue with Ruby 2.2.

I have tried Cucmber 2.0.0 as well as the 2.0.0.beta.3. Neither of them appear to be compatable in any way with either Ruby 2.0 or 2.2.

Every time I try to run one of my .feature files, I receive the same error. Cucumber claims to be compatable with any version of Ruby >= 1.9.3 (https://rubygems.org/gems/cucumber), but this does not appear to be true.

Has anyone else seen this error? Has anyone else succesfully used Cucumber 2.0.0 with Ruby 2.0 or 2.2? If so, what gems are in your Gemfile and what specific update/version of ruby shows up when you run `ruby --version`?

**If I revert to an older version of Cucumber (I tried 1.3.3), I can run my .feature files correctly. But I am building a new test suite from scratch, and would like to take this opportunity to use the latest and greatest versions of all possible gems. I don't want to build my Gemfile around a deprecated version of Cucumber.

```
`Cucumber::Ast` no longer exists. These classes have moved into the `Cucumber::Core::Ast` namespace, but may not have the same API. (RuntimeError)
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-2.0.0/lib/cucumber/ast.rb:10:in `const_missing'
C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/RubyMine 6.3/rb/testing/patch/bdd/teamcity/cucumber/common.rb:210:in `scenario_outline?'
C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/RubyMine 6.3/rb/testing/patch/bdd/teamcity/cucumber/common.rb:218:in `tc_before_feature_element'
C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/RubyMine 6.3/rb/testing/patch/bdd/teamcity/cucumber/formatter_03103.rb:98:in `before_feature_element'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-2.0.0/lib/cucumber/formatter/ignore_missing_messages.rb:10:in `method_missing'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-2.0.0/lib/cucumber/formatter/legacy_api/adapter.rb:521:in `before'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-2.0.0/lib/cucumber/formatter/legacy_api/adapter.rb:394:in `switch_to_child'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-2.0.0/lib/cucumber/formatter/legacy_api/adapter.rb:316:in `switch_step_container'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-2.0.0/lib/cucumber/formatter/legacy_api/adapter.rb:242:in `after_test_case'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-2.0.0/lib/cucumber/formatter/legacy_api/adapter.rb:85:in `after_test_case'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-2.0.0/lib/cucumber/formatter/legacy_api/adapter.rb:37:in `after_test_case'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-2.0.0/lib/cucumber/formatter/fanout.rb:16:in `block in method_missing'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-2.0.0/lib/cucumber/formatter/fanout.rb:15:in `each'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-2.0.0/lib/cucumber/formatter/fanout.rb:15:in `method_missing'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.1.3/lib/cucumber/core/test/runner.rb:18:in `test_case'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.1.3/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:21:in `describe_to'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-2.0.0/lib/cucumber/filters/prepare_world.rb:11:in `test_case'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.1.3/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:21:in `describe_to'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-2.0.0/lib/cucumber/filters/apply_around_hooks.rb:8:in `test_case'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.1.3/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:21:in `describe_to'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-2.0.0/lib/cucumber/filters/apply_after_hooks.rb:5:in `test_case'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.1.3/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:21:in `describe_to'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-2.0.0/lib/cucumber/filters/apply_before_hooks.rb:5:in `test_case'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.1.3/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:21:in `describe_to'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-2.0.0/lib/cucumber/filters/apply_after_step_hooks.rb:8:in `test_case'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.1.3/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:21:in `describe_to'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-2.0.0/lib/cucumber/filters/activate_steps.rb:8:in `test_case'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.1.3/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:21:in `describe_to'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-2.0.0/lib/cucumber/filters/quit.rb:11:in `test_case'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.1.3/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:21:in `describe_to'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.1.3/lib/cucumber/core/test/filters/locations_filter.rb:17:in `block in done'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.1.3/lib/cucumber/core/test/filters/locations_filter.rb:16:in `each'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.1.3/lib/cucumber/core/test/filters/locations_filter.rb:16:in `done'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.1.3/lib/cucumber/core/filter.rb:61:in `done'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.1.3/lib/cucumber/core/test/filters/tag_filter.rb:18:in `done'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.1.3/lib/cucumber/core/compiler.rb:23:in `done'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.1.3/lib/cucumber/core/gherkin/parser.rb:31:in `done'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.1.3/lib/cucumber/core.rb:29:in `parse'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-core-1.1.3/lib/cucumber/core.rb:18:in `compile'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-2.0.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:70:in `run!'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-2.0.0/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:38:in `execute!'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-2.0.0/bin/cucumber:9:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby200/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby200/bin/cucumber:23:in `<top (required)>'
-e:1:in `load'
```

**Update: When I run the file through the `Windows Shell` it runs successfully with no errors.

Comment: This looks like it's a RubyMine problem. Can you try running a feature in terminal/PowerShell/cmd?

Comment: When I run using `cucumber <feature file>` I get an error saying that steps are undefined, but they are defined. They are in the `step definitions` directory, where they should be...

Comment: What's your path to the feature file? Is it located in a subdirectory under features? Sounds like you need to invoke Cucumber a little differently: `cucumber -r features features/<path_to_feature_file>`.

Comment: My feature file is entitled android_phone_responsiveness.feature, and it is located in `C:\workspace\inside_test_automation\features\scenarios`. My step definitions are located in `C:\workspace\inside_test_automation\features\step_definitions`

Comment: When I run `cucumber -r features features/C:\workspace\inside_test_automation\features\scenarios\android_phone_responsiveness.feature` I get an error, and I will post a screen shot of the stack trace in my OP.

Comment: Sorry, when I said `<path_to_feature_file>`, I meant relative path. I should have been more specific. From the `inside_test_automation` directory, run this: `cucumber -r features features/scenarios/android_phone_responsiveness.feature`.

Answer (score 14):

Symptom:
You can run your test under cucumber command line ok but cannot run it under RubyMine, you got error:

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 3..4)
Error creating formatter: Teamcity::Cucumber::Formatter (ArgumentError)
C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/RubyMine 7.0.4/rb/testing/patch/bdd/teamcity/cucumber/formatter_03103.rb:22:in `initialize'
```

I have found a simpler solution:
Just go to `Rubymine -> Run -> Edit Configuration` , go to Runner options, add
`"--format pretty"` .This will over write the not compatible Teamcity issue and run smoothly.

Comment: Thanks!  Direct hit for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Few of the direct answer to problem, Saves my day! :-)

Answer (score 1):

With the help of @Johnson, I pinpointed the issue. It's caused by the `TeamCity formatter` which comes as part of every (or at least version 6.x and 7.x) Rubymine installation.

TeamCity formatter has a directory named `cucumber`, which can be found at `JetBrains\RubyMine 6.3\rb\testing\patch\bdd\teamcity\cucumber`. This directory contains a file named `common.rb`.

I modified the method named `scenario_outline?`, found on line 208 of common.rb, which is located at:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\RubyMine 6.3\rb\testing\patch\bdd\teamcity\cucumber`

I commented out the current definition of this method, and rewrote it as this:

```
def scenario_outline?(feature_element)
         if defined? ::Cucumber::Core::Ast
           feature_element.class == ::Cucumber::Core::Ast::ScenarioOutline
         else
           feature_element.class == ::Cucumber::Ast::ScenarioOutline
         end
end
```

This has fixed my issue and I can successfully run Cucumber tests through Rubymine.

I suppose that the over-arching issue here is that the TeamCity formatter does not seem to be compatible with Cucumber 2.0.0., since the `Ast` module at `::Cucumber::Ast::ScenarioOutline` has been placed inside the `Core` module at `::Cucumber::Core::Ast::ScenarioOutline`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [@FluffyKittens solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31191747/711006) works. However, the issue for me was RubyMine 2016. Installing RubyMine 2017 solved the issue for me. I guess there is a relationship between RubyMine 2017 and Cucumber 3.1.